# Facebook LikeView not working on Android Adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I have this code inside an adapter:

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeView);
likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType("http://facebook.com/751220098357471_752181024928045", LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
```

When I click the "Like" Button, the application crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'activity' cannot be null`

But working this code on Activity works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten to add this line.."LikeView.setFragment(this);" pass the context of your activity class. I done it with the fragment.

LikeView facebookLikeView = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_like_button);
        facebookLikeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
        facebookLikeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
        facebookLikeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        facebookLikeView.setFragment(this);
        facebookLikeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                url,
                LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);